# ¿Como crear un trigger en mysql que al eliminar una fila de una tabla, me elimine una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo una tabla en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) de nombre **Contratos**  que tiene la sig. estructura:

```
----------------------
|id|nombre |fecha     |
----------------------
|1 |Emp1   |2015-02-12|
-----------------------
|2 |Emp2   |2016-02-11|
-----------------------
```

Cada vez que creo un contrato, este crea una base de datos con el **id** del contrato creado, ejemp: `NombreBD_1`.
Lo que busco es que cada vez que elimine un contrato me elimine la base de datos que tiene el **id** de esta, he investigado pero no entiendo muy bien como funcionan los triggers en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), pues me imagino que es la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas compañero, siento decirte que en el caso que comentas no es posible la utilización de un trigger porque éstos actuan sobre tablas y no sobre BBDD. Lo ideal sería utilizar una función o procedimiento que si actuan sobre la BBDD. Un ejemplo de lo que necesitas, podría ser:

```
delimiter //

create procedure nombre_procedimiento ( in id_contrato int(50), in nombre_BBDD string (20))

begin 
    DROP DATABASE nombre_BBDD;

end //  
delimiter ;
```

Para llamar al procedimiento, donde 1 es el `id` y entre comillas simples el nombre de la BBDD

```
call nombre_procedimiento (1,'nombre_BBDD');
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

no es posible realizar esto ya que por el formato de la sentencia `DROP` no puede recibir una variable indicando la DB a la cual se intenta borrar.

Una posible solución sería agregar una DB de trabajos, en la cual insertar la DB a borrar y luego con un script externo borrar los trabajos que estén en esta DB. Algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_tg BEFORE DELETE ON contratos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbs_a_borrar(nombre_db) VALUES(OLD.nombre);
END;
```

y luego algún script que tome los valores de esta DB y genere el SQL necesario para realizar el borrado.

saludos

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, primero crea el triger como te indican, y luego lo que debes hacer es llamar a un procedimiento que vamos a crear a continuacion:

```
 DROP procedure IF EXISTS `borrarBaseDeDatos`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `tubasededatosaqui`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `borrarBaseDeDatos`(nombreDB varchar(40))
BEGIN

    SET @deleteBase = CONCAT('DROP DATABASE ',@nombreDB);
    PREPARE eliminar FROM @deleteBase;
    EXECUTE eliminar;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE eliminar;
```

-- no debes olvidar hacer DEALLOCATE.
    END$$

```
DELIMITER ;
```

y lo unico que debes hacer es enviar el nombre de la base de datos que deseas eliminar, de la misma manera si llegas a necesitar puedes quitar los usuarios permisos y otros.

Espero te sea util.

Answer (score 0):

Años tarde pero con una nueva opción.

Con un tigger no se me ocurre debido a que dentro de los trigger no se permite opciones dinámicas. Sin embargo si con un *stored procedure*:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE borrar_y_eliminar_db(id_tabla int)
  BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM contratos WHERE id = id_tabla)
    THEN

      DELETE
        FROM contratos
        WHERE id = id_tabla;

      set @db_name = CONCAT('NombreBD_', id_tabla);
      set @body = CONCAT( 'DROP DATABASE ', @db_name, ';');

      PREPARE stmnt FROM @body;
      EXECUTE stmnt;

    ELSE
      SELECT CONCAT ('No existe el id: "', id_tabla, '" en la tabla contratos');
    END IF;

  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Que luego mandas a llamar con:

```
CALL borrar_y_eliminar_db(<numero de id>);
```

Primero revisa si existe el registro con el id ingresado y, si existe, entonces elimina el registro y luego procede a borrar la base de datos cuyo nombre construimos.